# How to set color & texture of NSPanel

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, panel

I have a standard NSPanel in a Menubar popup, and would like to give it a color (like red), as well as a soft/noise texture for a nice effect. How can I accomplish this (Interface Builder or Obj-c is welcome)?

Answer (score 0):

Subclass NSView and override the drawRecth: method.
Then, go to the IB and click on the content of the Panel. In the identity inspector, set the new subclass as the custom class.